# TouchesMoved method for two view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, touchesmoved, touches

In my app there are two view controllers. I wrote touchesmoved method in both the view controllers. But even if i touch on second view controller on simulator, the first VC touches moved method is called.

// for VCOne

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"first view vc move method");

     UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
     ThreadedView *secViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"threaded"];
     [self.view addSubview:secViewController.view];

     [self viewDidUnload];
}
```

So once the above method is called, it will navigate to second view controllers "ViewDIDLoad" method. In this file, i have written one more touches moved method.

// for VCTwo

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"second view vc move method");
}
```

Now if i touch in second view controller, the first VC touchesmethod is called instead of second VC touches method.

Is there any way to do this? I needed different touches moved method for different view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transit from first view controller to second view controller,
you can try this method: `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

In your `touchesMoved:withEvevt:` of first view controller

```
NSLog(@"first view vc move method");

UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
ThreadedView *secViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Threaded"];
[self presentModalViewController:secViewController animated:NO];
```

In second view controller, you can use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` to go back to first view controller.

Hope this will help.