# touchesMoved being called in wrong UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, touchesmoved

In my UIViewController (VC1) I have a button that brings a second viewController (VC2) onto the screen via segue modal.

In VC1.m I have touchesMoved code

if I think bring VC2 onto the screen and start swiping the touchesMoved code in VC1.m starts getting called???

How can I make it so that the touchesMoved code only gets called when VC1 is the highest "z-index?" most visible viewController? The one on top?

Anyone know a simple if statement?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does this help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741923/touchesmoved-method-for-two-view-controllers][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741923/touchesmoved-method-for-two-view-controllers

Comment: what do u use for transition ? UINavigation or modal ?

Comment: @bradenV2 Not at all... I already tried searching for this and couldn't find anything /: Probably using the wrong key terms though haha!

Comment: @KunalBalani Modal (In the first sentence of the question haha ;) thank you for asking though!!! I still can't figure this out ahhhh)

Comment: why don't u just do VC1.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO when u do a present and in dismiss enable it again

Comment: @KunalBalani I would but the problem is, on my real project, I have like 15 view controllers that I can access from the home screen, and they all go back to that screen, and I'd have to add the code to 15 .m files... I'd rather know of a way of checking which viewController is currently at the top of my segue :)

Comment: you can use view.window property to check if a view is visible or not.